# Algorithm of java.util.zip

Tags: java, algorithm

What algorithm does `java.util.zip` is using in compression? LZW, huffman, run-length? Thanks

Comment: Please read this [http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/zip/package-summary.html](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/zip/package-summary.html)

Comment: did you search on the net? Have a look at java docs of java.util.Zip

Comment: Actually I've been searching for algorithms in compression and I've been studying algos such as LZW, huffman and runlength in a week now but I didn't know that there's an algo such as DEFLATE. I'm also been reading the api but I really have no idea that DEFLATE is also an algorithm until now. I thought it's only one of the objects in java. Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at the package description.

[Package Summary](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/zip/package-summary.html)

It says it uses the DEFLATE compression algorithm.

[DEFLATE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DEFLATE)